# iText : PdfCopy with many pages is too slow

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, itext

I am trying to generate a pages PDF file that has about 400 pages. This PDF is generated from a single template file.

We did as this. (Our app is working on GAE/J)

```
try (GcsInputChannel inputChannel =
    gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(templatefile, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) {

    byte[] inputBytes = getBytes(Channels.newInputStream(inputChannel));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, baos);
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    for (Integer keyNumber : keyList) {
        LOGGER.info("Copy page:" + keyNumber);
        PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(inputBytes);
        Set<String> fieldNameSet =
            new HashSet<>(templateReader.getAcroFields().getFields().keySet());
        for (String fieldName : fieldNameSet) {
            templateReader.getAcroFields().renameField(fieldName, fieldName + "_" + keyNumber);
        }
        copy.addDocument(templateReader);
    }
    copy.close();
    document.close();

    // Set field values in each page.
            :

}
```

`PdfCopy` becomes slower and slower as pages are increasing.

First few pages:

```
17:36:33.095 Copy page:1 
17:36:33.733 Copy page:2 
17:36:34.435 Copy page:3 
17:36:35.237 Copy page:4
```

Around 150th page:

```
17:42:38.275 Copy page:145 
17:42:53.609 Copy page:146 
17:43:09.019 Copy page:147 
17:43:28.576 Copy page:148
```

Each loop needs less than 1 second at the beginning, but needs more than 15 seconds around the 150th page. It will need more time around the end of the file (We didn't measure it because it was too slow and we aborted the program.)

We know we must not close `PdfReader` inside the loop as answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469286/merging-of-pdf-with-digital-signature-with-itext-5-4-0-or-greatest-gives-error).

How can we improve the performance?

Comment: You never "release" the reader (`copy.freeReader(reader);`), and you are referring to a post that is more than 3 years old. I thought we already solved the problem of not being able to close the `reader`. Is there a reason why you are using iText 5? iText 5 is "end of life"; it was replaced by iText 7. iText 7 isn't backward compatible with iText 5. The code to merge documents is much simpler in iText 7.

Comment: "How can we improve the performance?" consider multithreading, if possible, to improve performance https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html

Comment: "How can we improve the performance?" consider multithreading, if possible, to improve performance https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html

Comment: Thanks for comment. We will consider to migrate to iText7, but we already have developped on iText5. `copy.freeReader(reader)` got the error `It is not possible to free reader in mergeFields mode.` Could you let me know how I can fix?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes, there is a reason not to  move to iText 7: they are developing on Android/GAE, and iText 7 is not (yet) guaranteed to work on that platform.

Comment: OK, I forgot about the fact that the merging of forms requires access to the original documents. I fear you'll have to live with the process slowing down. You are creating a document with an enormous amount of fields. Are you sure you want to do that? What's the use case?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie We are creating invoice for our customers. We would like to make it in a single PDF file.

Comment: I don't understand. I understand your use case: creating a series of invoices that are in one PDF. And I understand your code: concatenating the same PDF many times creating an enormous amount of fields. What I don't understand is why you would use the latter to achieve the former. To me, that sounds like a very bad design. I have worked on many invoice projects, and never ever would I use such a design.

Comment: Could you let me know what solution should be used for creating invoice other than PDF form?